# Ambari Service Monitor is now a Kylo plugin jar

Tags: ambari, kylo

Kylo gives feature of ambari services.I try but find nothing how to use it.
That what a got from internet.

1. Modify/Ensure the connection properties are setup. The ambari connection parameters need to be moved out of the main kylo-services application.properties to a new file called ambari.properties

• Create a new file /opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/ambari.properties. Ensure    the owner of the file is kylo

• Add and configure the following properties in that file:

```
        ambariRestClientConfig.host=127.0.0.1
        ambariRestClientConfig.port=8080
        ambariRestClientConfig.username=admin
        ambariRestClientConfig.password=admin
        ambari.services.status=HDFS,HIVE,MAPREDUCE2,SQOOP
```

2. Copy the

   /opt/kylo/setup/plugins/kylo-service-monitor-ambari-0.8.0.jar to /
   opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin
   cp /opt/kylo/setup/plugins/kylo-service-monitor-ambari-0.8.0.jar /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin/

Comment: i want know how is these useful ambari service with kylo. How to achieve it with kylo.Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the solution by following above steps. You can see ambari jobs status in kylo under service tab.

as much services as you under this property in bleow property. Like HIVE,HDFS etc.All that services can be seen under this service tab in kylo. 
ambari.services.status=HDFS,HIVE,MAPREDUCE2,SQOOP,TEZ,HBASE,PIG,KAFKA,SPARK,ZOOKEEPER,YARN,FLUME,ACCUMULO,AMBARIINFRA,AMBARIMETRICS,ATLAS,KNOX,LOGSEARCH,SPARK,SPARK2,MAHOUT,SLIDER